# React/Jest/React-Testing-Library: Changes to files are not recognized by Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

While attempting to test my React app using Jest/React-Testing-Library, Jest fails to recognize changes I've made to my files.

Current setup: Parcel for rendering, but I have a .babelrc file with the following:

```
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

Issue: I have a static favicon.ico named "moai" which was causing errors.

The exact error:

> ```
> ReferenceError: moai is not defined.
> ```

However, I commented out the code containing that image, and the changes are not shown.

I've tried the following:

1. changing my npm script in package.json to `"test": "jest --watchAll --no-cache"`
2. pushing changes to git
3. clearing the cache using `jest --clearcache`
4. adding the following to my package.json (should fix the original error with jest not being able to recognize images, but is not being recognized by jest):

```
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|ico|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
  },
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please let me know if you need to see any config files, etc.

Comment: Check that you haven't compiled tests into your lib/dist folder, and that those are the tests being run.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it. However, it may have to do with some other transpiling error.

Comment: Does the `styleMock.js` file exist and is the directory correct?